# Sub process execution failing with std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string

Tags: c++, python-2.7, subprocess, pipe, abi

I am trying to execute a binary(my_binary) from a python script abc.py as following.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import logging
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %
    (levelname)-8s %(message)s',datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y 
    %H:%M:%S',filename='/var/home/root/root.txt',filemode='w')

    os.environ["ABCDE"]="x.x.x.x"
    os.environ["USER"]="user"
    os.environ["PASSWORD"]="password"

    p1 = Popen(["/var/home/root/my_binary","exec"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    out, err=p1.communicate()
    logging.info(out)
    return out,err

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         out,err = run(sys.argv[1:])
         logging.info(out)
         if( out.strip() == "Success: Check:"):
         print "Success: OK:"
```

If I execute this abc.py python program directly on the terminal, the binary my_binary will get executed.

But when I am trying to run the program from another c++ (using pipe in a similar way as above) program(say xyz.cpp), my_binary is failing to execute.

Note:

```
  The xyz.cpp is built with gcc(libstdc++.so.7).

  The my_binary is built with gcc(libstdc++.so.6).

  my_binary is built with "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" as the .so used in 
  my_binary are built using older g++(v 4.5).
```

The ldd o/p for my_binary

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2c9ff000)
    libx.so.0 => /opt/lib/libx.so.0 (0x00007f6caa7f6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6caa5d9000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6caa4be000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6caa23a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6caa224000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6ca9e8f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6ca9c8b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6cab1e0000)
```

ldd o/p for xyz.cpp

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff62dff000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3b736af000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3b734ab000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3b72dc2000)
    libstdc++.so.7 => /opt/lib64/libstdc++.so.7 (0x00007f3b7204e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3b71dc9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3b71db2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3b71a1e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3b738d2000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f3b70a73000)
```

objdump -T my_binary|fgrep GLIBC

```
    GLIBCXX_3.4
    GLIBC_2.2.5
    GLIBC_2.4
```

objdump -T xyz.cpp|fgrep GLIBC

```
    GLIBC_2.3.2
    GLIBC_2.2.5
    GLIBCXX_7.0
```

The backtrace is:

```
    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x00007f80a3f39495 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00007f80a3f3ac75 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00007f80a528a0d5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () 
    from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #3  0x00007f80a5288166 in ?? () from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #4  0x00007f80a5288193 in std::terminate() () from 
    /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #5  0x00007f80a52883e6 in __cxa_throw () from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #6  0x00007f80a52e3262 in std::__throw_logic_error(char const*) () from 
    /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #7  0x00007f80a52ef6f1 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>
    (char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, 
    std::forward_iterator_tag) ()
    from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
    #8  0x00007f80a52efac8 in std::basic_string<char, 
    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char 
    const*, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
    from /opt/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

All the required shared as well as static libraries are present in the env.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the actual code that causes the problem?

Comment: Code is breaking for a function call of a Library(.so).